# How to get Browserify, Babel, and Coverage working together in Karma?

Tags: karma-runner, babeljs, code-coverage, browserify, isparta

I'm growing weary of trying to get node libraries to work properly together, but it's part of the job, so here goes.

I have an ES6 application intended for a browser. I have a set of unit tests for my files that I'm bringing up from when my application was written in ES5. I use Browserify to handle importing/exporting modules and bundling my distro. This works fine when running the application in the browser. I can successfully Browserify the source and spec files and run the tests, and the tests pass. I'm very close to getting this working.

The only issue is the coverage. The closest I've come is showing coverage on the karma-browserify generated files, which each look like this:

```
require('/absolute/path/to/the/corresponding/file.js');
```

And the coverage obviously shows as 100% for all files, because each one is just one line.

This is my karma.conf.js:

```
import babelify from 'babelify';
import isparta  from 'isparta';
import paths    from './paths';

var normalizeBrowserName = (browser) => browser.toLowerCase().split(/[ /-]/)[0];

export default function(config) {
    config.set({
        basePath: '..',
        browsers: ['PhantomJS'],
        frameworks: ['browserify', 'jasmine'],
        files: paths.test.files,
        preprocessors: {
            'app/**/*.js': ['browserify', 'sourcemap', 'coverage'],
            [paths.test.testFiles]: ['babel'],
        },
        plugins: [
            'karma-babel-preprocessor',
            'karma-browserify',
            'karma-coverage',
            'karma-jasmine',
            'karma-junit-reporter',
            'karma-phantomjs-launcher',
            'karma-sourcemap-loader',
        ],
        autoWatch: false,
        colors: false,
        loggers: [{ type: 'console' }],
        port: 9876,
        reporters: ['progress', 'dots', 'junit', 'coverage'],
        junitReporter: {
            outputFile: paths.test.resultsOut,
            suite: '',
        },
        browserify: {
            debug: true,
            noParse: paths.js.noparse(),
            configure: (bundle) => {
                bundle.once('prebundle', () => bundle.transform(babelify.configure({ ignore: 'lib/!**!/!*' })));
            },
        },
        coverageReporter: {
            instrumenters: { isparta },
            instrumenter: {
                [paths.test.cover]: 'isparta',
            },
            reporters: [
                { type: 'text', },
                { type: 'html', dir: paths.test.coverageOut, subdir: normalizeBrowserName },
                { type: 'cobertura', dir: paths.test.coverageOut, subdir: '.', file: 'coverage.xml' },
            ],
        },
        logLevel: config.LOG_DEBUG,
    });
};
```

I really have no idea how any of these libraries work, so I don't know where to start in debugging this. I understand that the ordering of the preprocessors matters, so that Browserify runs on the source files, feeds the resulting link files into the source map generator, then the source map generator feeds the resulting whatever into karma-coverage. But there's some loss of communication between Browserify and whatever handles the coverage. Isparta (which uses istanbul behind the scenes) has no idea that browserify is running, and I don't know what it sees.

If anyone has any experience with testing modularized ES6 WITH proper code coverage, please let me know if I'm on the right track or if I should try something else.

Answer (score 5):

This is the configuration that worked for me, note that I am using browserify-istanbul rather than isparata.

```
var istanbul = require('browserify-istanbul');

module.exports = function(config) {
    config.set({
        basePath: '',
        frameworks: ['browserify', 'mocha'],
        files: [
          'test/**/*Spec.js'
        ],
        exclude: [
          '**/*.sw?'
        ],
        preprocessors: {
          'test/**/*Spec.js': ['browserify', 'coverage']
        },
        browserify: {
          debug: true,
          transform: [
            ['babelify', {
              ignore: /node_modules/
            }],
            istanbul({
              ignore: ['test/**', '**/node_modules/**']
            })
          ],
          extensions: ['.jsx']
        },

        babelPreprocessor: {
          options: {
            sourceMap: 'inline'
          },
           sourceFileName: function(file) {
            return file.originalPath;
          }
        },
        coverageReporter: {
          dir: 'coverage/',
          reporters: [
            { type: 'text-summary' }
          ]
        },
        browserNoActivityTimeout: 180000,
        reporters: ['coverage', 'progress'],
        port: 9876,
        colors: true,
        logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
        autoWatch: true,
        browsers: ['Chrome'],
        singleRun: false
    });
};
```

it was a massive pain to get working.

hope that helps

Comment: I get the html output compressed to exclude/import so, everytime it says all files have tests when it's not true. All files in the html report contain `typeof require === "function" && require(MY-FILE)`

Comment: This helped me, but I had to tweak it a bit. In `preprocessors: []` for example, instead of a single entry as you did, I separated in two entries my src and my test files, since I didn't want to run the 'coverage' preprocessor on my own tests, otherwise I would be measuring the coverage in the test files themselves. I also had to do other tweaks... If I have time later I will post my solution.

Answer (score 2):

**HOW TO: Karma + Babel + React + Browserify + Istanbul**

*I THINK I GOT IT.*

If I don't, ping me gus+overflow@mythril.co

Not sure if the previous answer not working has to do with using jasmine instead of mocha but I got it working with these settings.

**Required Packages:** apart from the obvious (React, Karma, Jasmine, Browserify)

```
isparta             - an Istanbul instrumenter for ES6
browserify-istanbul - a browserify transform
babelify            - another browserify transform
babel               - JS compiler
babel-preset-2015   - ES6 compile preset
babel-preset-react  - React compile preset
```

**Create a .babelrc file** in your root dir.
I was very confused as to where to place babel options within the tools, but most (and these) babel tools *will* look for a `.babelrc`

```
{
  "presets": ["es2015", "react"],
  "sourceMap": "inline"
}
```

**karma.config.js:**

```
const isparta = require('isparta');
const istanbul = require('browserify-istanbul');

module.exports = function (config) {
  config.set({

    basePath: '',

    browsers: ['Firefox', 'Chrome', 'PhantomJS', 'Safari'],

    captureConsole: true,

    clearContext: true,

    colors: true,

    files: [

      // you need this for Phantom
      'node_modules/phantomjs-polyfill/bind-polyfill.js',

      // import any third party libs, we bundle them in another gulp task
      './build/libs/vendor-bundle.js',

      // glob for spec files
      '__PATH_TO_SPEC_FILES_/*.spec.js'
    ],

    frameworks: ['jasmine', 'browserify'],

    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,

    preprocessors: {

      // I had to NOT include coverage, the browserify transform will handle it
      '__PATH_TO_SPEC_FILES_/*.spec.js': 'browserify'
    },

    port: 9876,

    reporters: ['progress', 'coverage'],

    browserify: {

      // we still use jQuery for some things :(
      // I don't think most people will need this configure section
      configure: function (bundle) {
        bundle.on('prebundle', function () {
          bundle.external(['jquery']);
        });
      },

      transform: [

        // this will transform your ES6 and/or JSX
        ['babelify'],

        // (I think) returns files readable by the reporters
        istanbul({
          instrumenter: isparta, // <--module capable of reading babelified code 
          ignore: ['**/node_modules/**', '**/client-libs/**']
        })
      ],

      // our spec files use jsx and so .js will need to be compiled too
      extensions: ['.js', '.jsx'],

      // paths that we can `require()` from
      paths: [
        './node_modules',
        './client-libs',
        './universal'
      ],

      debug: true
    },

    coverageReporter: {
      reporters: [
        { type: 'html', dir: 'coverage/Client' },
        { type: 'text-summary' }
      ]
    }
  });
};
```

Comment: I couldn't make it work without setting the coverage preprocessor and the transform was failing, ended up with a mix from your answer and Derek's one.

Answer (score 0):

With Karma, I think it would look something like this(?):

```
// Karma configuration
'use strict';

    let babelify = require( 'babelify' );
    let browserify = require('browserify');
    let browserifyBabalIstanbul = require('browserify-babel-istanbul');
    let isparta = require('isparta');

    browserify: {
                debug: true,
                transform: [
                    browserifyBabalIstanbul({
                        instrumenter: isparta,
                        instrumenterConfig: { babel: { presets: ["es2015"] } },
                        ignore: ['**/node_modules/**', '**/unitest/**']
                    }),
                    [ babelify, { presets: ["es2015"] } ]
                ]
            },
```

see the following link : [Find a good way to get a coverage report with karma?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38953353/find-a-good-way-to-get-a-coverage-report-with-karma/38972723?noredirect=1#comment65300214_38972723)